# How to serialize nested collection in class?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I have classes:

```
[Serializable]
class Data1
{
    public Data1(){}
    public string Street{get;set}
    public string State{get;set;}
}

[Serializable]
class Transfer
{
public string Name{ get; set; }
public List<Data1> Address{ get; set; }
}
```

After deserializing I get `Address = Null`.
How to serialize Collection with data?
My serialize code:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, obj);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you just have public Data1 Address{ get; set; }?  If so what if you use a normal array in instead of a list?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the following Data1: `[Serializable] class Data1 { public string Field { get; set; } }`  Can you show the actual classes?

Comment: Still works for me with no bug.  How are you deserializing the data?

Comment: Sorry my friends, that's a bug in code.I found it and fixed it.

Comment: Maybe we should close this thread?